# SQL Join on Tables

Tags: sql

Trying to join these tables to get desired column out (see picture 1) but after the third entry I am getting duplicate rows. So my question is would an inner join on the id values fix this?

[image: Current Output]

from...

```
select m.make, m.model, car.price, color.color, car.mileage, carlot.lotid
from makemodel as m, color, carlot, car;
```

[image: Database Relationships]

Comment: Please do not use antiquated comma separated tables in your FROM clause. That's been outdated for 20 years or more. Use specific JOIN statements instead. There should never ever be even a single comma in a FROM. If that's how you're learning, find a new teacher/book/tutorial that is more recent than the mid 1990s.

Comment: `select distinct` would eliminate duplicate do matter your other operations

Answer (score 2):

You actually need to specify the conditions under hwich the rows should be joined.

What you've writen is...

- Take the `makemodel` table
- For every row, copy it and join it with every row in the `color` table
- For every row you have now, copy it and join it with every row in the `carlot` table
- For every row you have now, copy it and join it with every row in the `car` table

That's known as `CROSS JOIN` or "Cartessian Product".

To avoid such mistakes, don't use `,` to join tables together.  Use `JOIN` syntax instead.  *(Which was adopted as the ANSI-92 standard nearly 30 years ago.  The syntax you're using is nearly 3 decades out of date.)*

```
SELECT
  m.make, m.model, car.price, color.color, car.mileage, carlot.lotid
FROM
  makemodel as m
INNER JOIN
  car
    ON car.mmid = m.mmid
INNER JOIN
  color
    ON color.colorid = car.colorid
INNER JOIN
  carlot
    ON carlot.carid = car.carid
```

Comment: INNER keyword could be skipped. It's default type of join

Comment: @BogdanMart - I would ***never*** personally endorse that.  Code should be clear and explicit where possible, leaving out the `INNER` key word works, but so would `,` and moving the predicates to a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: IMO that's matter of taste and project code-syle. INNER JOIN don't provide more information than simple JOIN to the reader of code. I'm writing inner only if syntax forces me, as when I need to write `INNER LOOP JOIN` and loop keyword requires that specifier.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using join here. You are using a [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) (or a [cross join](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php))of 4 tables. So all values are copied for each row.

You need either add where clause and join there:

```sql
select m.make, m.model, car.price, color.color, car.mileage, carlot.lotid
from makemodel as m, color, carlot, car
where m.mmid=car.mmid and car.colorid=color.colorid and carlot.carid=car.carid
;
```

Also as @Ken White suggests, it's better to use join syntax here. I won't agree that comma separated from is bad practice, and it has it's uses but this is not a case.

you could rewrite query as

```
select m.make, m.model, car.price, color.color, car.mileage, carlot.lotid
from car
join makemodel as m ON m.mmid=car.mmid
join color ON  car.colorid=color.colorid
join carlot ON  carlot.carid=car.carid
```

Which would make intents more clear and code more readable. Now we can see that car is primary table.

Additionally if you are using god forsaken MySQL (I mean it's really bad DB in my opinion) then it has  feature of natural join and you could rewrite it as following:

```
select m.make, m.model, car.price, color.color, car.mileage, carlot.lotid
from car
natural join makemodel as m 
natural join color 
natural join carlot
```

It would automatically join by columns with the same name. Perhaps this feature tricked you into writing tables separated by commas. This feature is useful when columns have same names in different tables, but it's controversial, as it's not clear from code how join would be performed. I'd suggest not relying on this feature a lot.